# Is OR (`||`) allowed when defining concepts?

Tags: c++, c++-concepts

I see many examples of "composite" concepts being defined with `&&`, but none where `||` is used. This makes me wonder whether it makes sense to use `||`. It seems to me that using `||` would allow to specify a concept that has an effect similar to overloading (i.e. ad-hoc polymorphism), but with a closed set of possibilities.

For a set of "primitive" concepts C1,...,CN, is it valid to write

```
 C1 || ... || CN
```

as a "composite" concept?

Comment: Could you please give a concise code sample of what you're actually trying to do?

Comment: I'm not trying to do anything. I simply note that the syntax for chaining requirements for concepts uses `&&`, and this makes me wonder whether the related boolean operator `||` is valid also. Concepts is not even available on the compiler that I'm using, by the way, so even if I could write it -- which I can't because I'm only just starting to get to grips with Concepts TS -- the compiler would complain at me for doing so. Ergo no concise code sample.

Comment: Just check the [Disjunctions section](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constraints) from the reference please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use pretty much any constant expression in a constraint (including `||`). The only restriction is that those expressions must return `bool`.

One use of `||` could be to define sets of types that are known to share a common interface. For example, the Integral (`std::is_integral`) could be defined as the disjunction of a number of same-type constraints (`is_same<T, int>`). I wouldn't recommend doing this though. You should define concepts in an additive way.

Comment: This makes sense. I guess for `std::is_integral` it works because there is no syntactical way of specifying that a type is integral other than to say: integral is precisely this set of types. But for more complex concepts, I shouldn't be saying which precise types satisfy embody the concept; rather, I should specify the list of requirements, and this is typically done with &&.

Answer (score 3):

From [cpprenference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constraints)

> **Constraints**
>
> A constraint is a sequence of logical operations that specifies
> requirements on template arguments. They can appear within
> requires-expressions (see below) and directly as bodies of concepts
> There are 9 types of constraints:
>
> 1. conjunctions
> 2. disjunctions
> 3. predicate constraints
> 4. expression constraints (only in a requires-expression)
> 5. type constraints (only in a requires-expression)
> 6. implicit conversion constraints (only in a requires-expression)
> 7. argument deduction constraints (only in a requires-expression)
> 8. exception constraints (only in a requires-expression)
> 9. parametrized constraints (only in a requires-expression)

And

> **Disjunctions**
>
> Disjunction of constraints P and Q is specified as P || Q.
> A disjunction of two constraints is satisfied if either constraint is satisfied. Disjunctions are evaluated left to right and short-circuited (if the left constraint is satisfied, template argument deduction into the right constraint is not attempted). User-defined overloads of operator|| are not allowed in constraint disjunctions.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was after. Are you aware of any concepts defined in the standard that make use of disjunction? EDIT: sorry, I saw an example in the link you provided: Ranges TS has `equal_to` which is a disjunction of `EqualityComparable` and `Same`.

Comment: No that I am aware of.  They still are not standard FWIK so things could change.

Comment: Newer drafts of Ranges TS use `||` in a couple other places, for example in the RandomAccessIterator concept.